# C++ round(49.5) returns 49 when called with variable (in Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, integer, double, rounding

I wrote the following code:

```
void InputNodeInstance::changeSize(QString side, float mult) {
    qDebug() << "width: " << width;
    double widthMultiplied = width * mult;
    qDebug() << "width * mult: " << width * mult;
    qDebug() << "widthMultiplied: " << widthMultiplied;
    qDebug() << "round(widthMultiplied): " << round(widthMultiplied);
    qDebug() << "round(49.5): " << round(49.5);
    width = width * mult + 0.5;
    qDebug() << "width: " << width;
}
```

And when I call the function with 0.9 as `mult`, I get this output:

```
width:  55
width * mult:  49.5
widthMultiplied:  49.5
round(widthMultiplied):  49
round(49.5):  50
width:  49
```

I guess the question is clear.
`widthMultiplied` is **49.5**.
`round(49.5)` returns **50**.
`round(widthMultiplied)` returns **49**.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read kefir's answer for background info. 
I think a full working solution (while you don't go too far with your numbers) could be:

```
int number = 55;
double mult = 0.9;
double roundedNumber = round( static_cast<double>( static_cast<int>( number * mult * 100. ) ) / 100 );
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens due to inaccuracy of the floating point numbers calculation. More info [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

The result of the `width * mult` multiplication is not exact 49.5 but something like 49.4999999, which is the reason for rounding your number to 49, not 50. Try it youself by setting the higher [precision](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setRealNumberPrecision) for your `qDebug` output:

```
qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision(20) << widthMultiplied;
```

Comment: Yes, probably you are right, I also kept that in mind, but the qDebug() prints 45.5 and not 45.49999999 . I thougt, the qDebug prints the whole number

Comment: @mep The default precision for `qDebug` is 6 fraction digits. The solution you posted can still fail with other numbers due to the reasons described in the linked articles.

Comment: But why does qDebug print 50 then? It should print 49.499999 instead. And if it rounds the number, like I wanted to do, the number can't be 49.499999 because the output is 50. Could it be a solution to round to one decimal places first and then rounding to a 0 digits number?

Comment: @mep The *last* fraction number (defined by the precision) is rounded by the *following* fraction number, that is why the `.499999` will be rounded to `.5` until the precision meets the number other than `9`.